# Applying properties of an inner product to prove inner products.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I was reading a chapter about inner products in a book on linear algebra and came across this question:

"a) Consider the vector space $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ of real polynomials of degree $\leq2$.

Which of the following forms of $P_2$ have inner products?

(1) $<p,q>=p(0)q(0)$

(2) $<p,q>=p(0)q(0)+p'(0)q'(0)+p''(0)q''(0)$

b) Calculate $<t+1, t^2+1>$ for each of the inner products in a)."

I know that these 4 properties have to be satisfied to prove it is an inner product:
$$1) \langle u+v,w \rangle=\langle u,w\rangle+\langle v,w\rangle$$
$$2) \langle\alpha v, w\rangle=\alpha \langle v,w\rangle$$
$$3) \langle v,w\rangle =\langle w,v\rangle$$
$$4) \langle v,v\rangle\geq 0$$

However I am not completely sure on how to apply the definition to my actual problem.
And also how do I apply b) to this?

Comment: Apply b) to what?   Part b) is just a calculation.   I suggest doing part b) first, in order to get a feel for this business. Click "Edit" above, and I will check your calculation.

Comment: b) doesn't require proving that these are inner products. For a), figure out what this means in terms of the provided inner product. For example. (1) 1) you're trying to show that given $3$ polynomials $p, q, r$ you have $(p+q)(0)r(0) = p(0)r(0) + q(0)r(0)$. Start with the left and see if you can get to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a)$: Each form **is** an inner product.

$b)$: Take $p(t) = t+1, q(t) = t^2+1 \implies p(0) = 1, p'(0) = 1, p''(0) = 0, q(0) = 1, q'(0) = 0, q''(0) = 2 \implies$

- $<p,q>_1 = p(0)q(0) = 1\cdot 1 = 1$
- $<p,q>_2 = 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 0 + 0\cdot 2 = 1$